# Unordered list unicode character 0x25E6 padding issue

Tags: javascript, react-native

Using [react-native-unordered-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unordered-list), When creating an unordered list using the unicode characters below, `0x25E6` has extra padding, how can I align them above each other?

```
0x2022 •
0x25E6 ◦
```

[image]

```
 import Unorderedlist from "react-native-unordered-list";
    export const TickContainer = ({ ticks }) => {
      return (
        <View style={forms.tickContainer}>
          {ticks.map((tick, index) => (
            <Unorderedlist
              bulletUnicode={tick.ticked ? "0x2022" : "0x25E6"}
              color={tick.ticked ? "green" : "black"}
            >
              <Text>{tick.label}</Text>
            </Unorderedlist>
          ))}
        </View>
      );
    };
```